# Swift UIButton With Icon and Text (not using edgeinsets)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I'm trying to get a button with an icon to the left of some text:

[image]

Having trouble with my understanding of UIButton. Adding a title to the button works fine:

```
import UIKit

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 25))
button.backgroundColor = .green
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
button.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
button.titleLabel!.backgroundColor = .blue
button.setTitle("639", for: .normal)
button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
```

[image]

but then when you add an image

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "test"), for: .normal)
button.imageView!.backgroundColor = .clear
button.imageView!.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

[image]

it keeps it's original size (300px) and pushes the title out the right side out of the buttons bounds. (can't see it in screenshot as its only showing button frame)

What am I doing wrong? Why does the image retain it's original width even though its been scaled down? What does `contentHorizontalAlignment` even do if it allows items to be pushed out of frame?

I'm aware that you can set insets but this is being used in a re-useable view so I can't hardcode values.

Thanks for the help

Comment: what do you want actually? i don't get it. share a picture of you expect

Comment: @elk_cloner updated op with picture of what I'm shooting for

Comment: I've just given you the solution.If it helps then hope you'll accept my answer. :)

Comment: > I'm aware that you can set insets but this is being used in a re-useable view so I can't hardcode values

Answer (score 2):

I just made a button just like what you said.

By the way why don't you use inset.Apple has given us the opportunity to use this.Then why shouldn't we use this?

**Note:** You have to make trial and error to position the image and text correctly.

[image]

**Autolayout:**

[image]

**And inset:**

[image]

If it's not accurate i said you have to make trial and error. happy coding. :)